# Pandas date range returns "could not convert string to Timestamp" for yyyy-ww

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns; `Sales` and `Date`.

```
dataset.head(10)


        Date    Sales
0   2015-01-02  34988.0
1   2015-01-03  32809.0
2   2015-01-05  9802.0
3   2015-01-06  15124.0
4   2015-01-07  13553.0
5   2015-01-08  14574.0
6   2015-01-09  20836.0
7   2015-01-10  28825.0
8   2015-01-12  6938.0
9   2015-01-13  11790.0
```

I want to convert the `Date` column from `yyyy-mm-dd` (e.g. `2015-06-01`) to `yyyy-ww` (e.g. `2015-23`), so I run the following piece of code:

```
dataset["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(dataset["Date"]).dt.strftime('%Y-%V')
```

Then I group by my `Sales` based on weeks, i.e.

```
data = dataset.groupby(['Date'])["Sales"].sum().reset_index()

data.head(10)

    Date    Sales
0   2015-01 67797.0
1   2015-02 102714.0
2   2015-03 107011.0
3   2015-04 121480.0
4   2015-05 148098.0
5   2015-06 132152.0
6   2015-07 133914.0
7   2015-08 136160.0
8   2015-09 185471.0
9   2015-10 190793.0
```

Now I want to create a date range based on the `Date` column, since I'm predicting sales based on weeks:

```
ds = data.Date.values
ds_pred = pd.date_range(start=ds.min(), periods=len(ds) + num_pred_weeks, 
freq="W")
```

However I'm getting the following error: `could not convert string to Timestamp` which I'm not really sure how to fix. So, if I use `2015-01-01` as the starting date of my date-import I get no error, which makes me realize that I'm using the functions wrong. However, I'm not sure how?

I would like to basically have a date range that spans weekly from the current week and then 52 weeks into the future.

Comment: Seems like you are refering to the wrong object, in your question above you insert the new dataframe in `data`, but in your `pd.data_range` line you call `ds`. Try this: `ds_pred = pd.date_range(start=data.min(), periods=len(data) + num_pred_weeks, freq="W")`

Comment: Could you check your Date column type after this your step: `data = dataset.groupby(['Date'])["Sales"].sum().reset_index()` is it object type?

Comment: It is weird bug :(

Comment: @Erfan Sorry, forgot to add a bit of code! My bad

Comment: @AT_asks yeah, it's a DataFrame

Comment: @Artem, I meant column type (Object/int/float...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think problem is want create minimum of `dataset["Date"]` column filled by strings in format `YYYY-VV`. But for pass to `date_range` need format `YYYY-MM-DD` or datetime object.

I found [this](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

> Several additional directives not required by the C89 standard are included for convenience. These parameters all correspond to ISO 8601 date values. These may not be available on all platforms when used with the strftime() method. The ISO 8601 year and ISO 8601 week directives are not interchangeable with the year and week number directives above. Calling strptime() with incomplete or ambiguous ISO 8601 directives will raise a ValueError.
>
> **%V** ISO 8601 week as a decimal number with Monday as the first day of the week. Week 01 is the week containing Jan 4.

Pandas 0.24.2 bug with `YYYY-VV` format:

```
dataset = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2015-06-01','2015-06-02']})
    
dataset["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(dataset["Date"]).dt.strftime('%Y-%V')
print (dataset)
      Date
0  2015-23
1  2015-23

ds = pd.to_datetime(dataset['Date'], format='%Y-%V')
print (ds)
```

> ValueError: 'V' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%V'

Possible solution is use `%U` or %W, check [this](http://strftime.org/):

> **%U** Week number of the year (Sunday as the first day of the week) as a zero padded decimal number. All days in a new year preceding the first Sunday are considered to be in week 0.
> **%W** Week number of the year (Monday as the first day of the week) as a decimal number. All days in a new year preceding the first Monday are considered to be in week 0.

```
dataset = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2015-06-01','2015-06-02']})

dataset["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(dataset["Date"]).dt.strftime('%Y-%U')
print (dataset)
      Date
0  2015-22
1  2015-22

ds = pd.to_datetime(dataset['Date'] + '-1', format='%Y-%U-%w')
print (ds)
0   2015-06-01
1   2015-06-01
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Or using data from original DataFrame in datetimes:

```
dataset = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2015-06-01','2015-06-02'],
                        'Sales':[10,20]})
 
dataset["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(dataset["Date"])
print (dataset)
        Date  Sales
0 2015-06-01     10
1 2015-06-02     20

data = dataset.groupby(dataset['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%V'))["Sales"].sum().reset_index()
print (data)
      Date  Sales
0  2015-23     30

num_pred_weeks = 5
ds = data.Date.values
ds_pred = pd.date_range(start=dataset["Date"].min(), periods=len(ds) + num_pred_weeks, freq="W")
print (ds_pred)
DatetimeIndex(['2015-06-07', '2015-06-14', '2015-06-21', 
               '2015-06-28',
               '2015-07-05', '2015-07-12'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='W-SUN')
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand OP correctly, but doesn't he simply want format `%Y-%W`?

Comment: @Erfan - it is different, I find difference [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strftime.htm)

Comment: @Erfan is right - I merely want to increment on weekly data (using pd.date_range or some other method). It seems like it doesn't recognize the formatting as a yyyy-ww format .

Comment: @Artem - yes, need datetime in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Comment: @jezrael - Argh, I see now. Hang on, might be able to use your second solution.

Comment: @Artem - yes, or last - simply use minimal of original data - there are datetimes in format `YYYY-MM-DD`

Answer (score 2):

If `ds` contains dates as string formatted as `'2015-01'` which should be `'%Y-%W'` (or `'%G-%V'` in datetime library) you have to add a day number to obtain a day. Here, assuming that you want the monday you should to:

```
ds_pred = pd.date_range(start=pd.to_datetime(ds.min() + '-1', format='%Y-%W-%w',
                                             periods=len(ds) + num_pred_weeks, freq="W")
```